# Visual Studio 2015 does not build my (blank) Cordova projects: Build fails without error

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-cordova

I am using Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 to create Cordova projects. The project gets created successfully and I am able to play around with the source code. Before I actually change something and I try to build the empty starting project, Visual Studio will give me the following build message:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: BlankCordovaApp4, Configuration: Debug Android ------

========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

The error List is completely empty and I cannot see anything in other output windows nor the command window.
I have looked around to activate the diagnostic log level when building (Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Build and Run > MSBuild output verbosity) but that didn't help... I'm still seeing the same non-descriptive message.

I am on Windows 10 with the following programs installed:

- Node JS 4.0.0
- Cordova installed with the npm tool (`npm install -g cordova`)
- Android Studio and its Emulators
- Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate Update 4
- Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise Edition (with Cordova Tools)

I have been successfully creating Cordova apps with Visual Studio 2013 with the tools and with Visual Studio 2015 RC. But I can't seem to make it work anymore in the current build.

I have tried Repairing Visual Studio as well as uninstalling and reinstalling it completely, without avail. I have also cleared the Cordova cache multiple times and tried to run Visual Studio from Administrator mode, but that didn't work either.

So the question actually is twofold:

1. Is there a way to see what actually is going wrong when I'm trying to build?
2. Has anybody else experienced this kind of issue and found a solution for it?

Comment: Personally I'd go for a unixy environment such as Cygwin, Linux or OSX.

Comment: You can try raising the trace level in the build output to see the underlying error. Go to Tools->Options then find the Project and Solutions->Build and Run

Comment: Hmm, I said in my original question that I've already done that. It's on diagnostic level. I still can't see any error messages... And if I try the same with an ASP.NET Web application, I now get spammed with build messages...

Comment: Sorry, missed that part. Another thing you can try is building through the CLI. `cordova build android` from the solution directory. That is basically what VS is doing for you anyway.

Comment: @EladLachmi your hint about raising trace level helped me , thanks :)

Comment: @MahmoudFarahat - Great! Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We connected to Diedrik's machine and debugged the problem. There is a bug in Visual Studio which we will fix shortly.

For now, here is a workaround:

1. Open Tools -> Options -> Tools for Apache Cordova -> Remote Agent Configuration
2. Set Enable remote iOS processing to “False”
3. Click OK
4. (Optional if remote build is needed) Re-open the options and set it back to “True”

Thank you for reporting this problem!

Comment: At this point I'm still able to continue with the command line tools from cordova, so it's more a big annoyance than really a trouble ;). Ok, I will keep you posted.

Comment: That's good news but I would really like to know why the IDE isn't working. If you can still repro the issue, please get in touch with us so we can diagnose and fix the problem.

Comment: So together with the VS Cordova Tools team we found the culprit in my case. 
To put it into context: A little while back, still with VS 2015 RC, I had activated the Remote Agent Configuration to connect with a Mac and try to debug the cordova App from VS. This didn't pose any problems.
Since the release of VS 2015, I still had this configuration set up and the build agent failed when I did not have a connection to the Remote Mac.

Comment: I'm really glad we got to the bottom of this. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced it and I fixed it closing everything and restarting windows after that it hasn't happened again, I think Visual Studio 2015 has a bug or something

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was having the same issue after upgrading VS 2015 RC to Enterprize. I then run the installer again and this time selected Cordova Update 4 rather than 3 which was selected by default. After install completed, I was able to build Cordova apps successfully. Didn't have to change anything in remote iOS processing.